# Printer doesn't work with laptop

Tags: printing, canon

I just recently bought a Canon Pixma MG3550 printer and the disk that was supplied doesn't work with wine, and the driver database doesn't have the model, how can I get it to work with my laptop? I'm running Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LT .

Comment: Here's a lead for you to run down yourself. I can't test it, because I don't own one. http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/02/install-canon-printer-for-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: I do not think wine has anything to do with installing drivers for your printer. You need a linux driver not windows.

Answer (score 0):

The following link [upubuntu](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-install-canon-pixma-mp-canon-mx.html) will show you how install Canon Pixma IP and Pixma MG series.

But the source of how to install the Canon drivers for Ubuntu comes from the following website called [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-stable) where a ppa with stable canon drivers must be installed via the command line terminal.